# NFA for (a+b)?c

Tags: regex, nfa

I need NFA for regex

```
(a+b)?c
```

As far as I understand, it should contains epsilon from zero node to node before last one (to match string "c", for example).

To check my NFA I use "[Regular Expression to NFA Visializaton web service](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa)",
but graph for my regex on this service does not contain epsilon from zero node.

Is it bug in service, or I misunderstand something?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if the source for the web service is available somewhere?

Comment: the online checker you are using is not working... It should show a path accepting the string `"c"` and it forces to pass through the (a+b) subexpression.

Comment: Thinking that the `?` operator might not be implemented correctly, I tried algebraically substituting it to `((a+b)|)c`.  The web service bombs with a "Something blew up. (Error 500) message."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a bug. If I try `(aa*b)?c` which should be the same language the NFA looks very different (and correct). Also when I try using a automata library I've develop myself some time ago I get this:

`./fatool --in 're:^(a+b)?c$' --out dot:- | dot -Gdpi=70 -Tpng -onfa.png /dev/stdin`
[image: NFA]

The library if you are interested: https://github.com/wader/libfa

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a bug to me. Trying to reduce the problem, `a+?` fails as well.

There is also another bug where `a|`, which should be equivalent to `a?`, causes an HTTP error 500 from the server.

Playing devil's advocate, it is possible they ignore certain cases because they are not closed under regular languages. This would be possible if they accept some non-regular extensions to the expression language.

Maybe your example is not really a regular language. If that were the case then the tool may be performing as expected. That is, if given a regular expression which denotes a regular language then it produces an NFA and DFA which recognises that regular language. However, the converse may not hold.

For the sake of adding more heft to this reply, I'll show that your example is indeed a regular language.

First we define what a regular language is. Empty `ε` and any symbol of an alphabet is a regular language. If `x` and `y` are regular languages then: concatenation `x·y`, choice `x|y`, and repetition `x*` are regular languages.

For notation, precedence from lowest to highest is: `|`, `·`, `*`. Additionally, we add the usual parentheses and they have the highest precedence. Both `|` and `·` are associative, so for example `(a·b)·c` and `a·(b·c)` will be written as `a·b·c`.

Now it can be shown the example is a regular language by constructing it. It is assumed the alphabet contains 'a', 'b', and 'c'. For brevity, this deduction tree is not labeled with the rules used, but they are easily inferred.

```
    --
    a
--  --
a   a*
-----   --
 a·a*   b
----------   --
  a·a*·b     ε
 --------------   --
   (a·a*·b)|ε     c
 ------------------- 
    ((a·a*·b)|ε)·c
```

These definitions can be assumed.

```
x+ ≡ x·x*
x? ≡ x|ε
xy ≡ x·y
```

Then by using the definitions the example can be obtained. `+` and `?` have the same precedence as `*`.

```
((a·a*·b)|ε)·c
((a+·b)|ε)·c
((a+b)|ε)·c
(a+b)?·c
(a+b)?c
```

This is not the only way regular languages can be understood. Also, I have not defined what words are actually in the constructed language, so the equivalence to your example is taken for granted – by the conventions used I hope the equivalence is obvious enough.